# DebugBreak() equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

In C# is there any statement equivalent to `DebugBreak()`? I want to invoke the debugger when ever a particular condition is met.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the [`Break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) method of the [`Debugger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.aspx) class, in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace:

```
Debugger.Break();
```

Now, there's also a different way you can add conditional breakpoints, without mucking about with adding code to your project.

*This of course only works when already running your program through the debugger*

What you can do is first add a regular breakpoint at the location where you want your debugger to stop, then right-click the red dot for the breakpoint:

[image: breakpoint right-click menu]

and then edit the condition to fit your needs:

[image: breakpoint condition dialog]

This will then be symbolized with a small + inside your breakpoint dot:

[image: conditional breakpoint]

Comment: You can't declare a breakpoint on a complex conditions IN THAT WAY(using the conditional clause).

Comment: The nice thing about Debugger.Break is that it works even if no debugger is attached yet.

Comment: @Artur There's a limit to the complexity, yes, I just added it to complete the answer. The correct answer to the particular question is still `Debugger.Break();`

Comment: I suppose that Debugger.Launch() shoud not be allowed from production code, so I need #if statement, Debbuger.Launch() also completely breaks security and can lead to unexpected results. On the other side Debug.Assert throws an exception on a codition met (allowin to break under VS IDE), skips by the compiler completely on a release build, so this is a good alternative, not bad one.

Comment: Also, you should keep in mind that Conditional Breakpoints slow down your application significantly. Debugging a loop and only breaking in some cases can take ages.

Answer (score 18):

Concerning the other answers, I prefer using `Debugger.Launch()`.

If the application is not already running in a debugger, `Launch()` will call up the debugger dialog allowing you to attach Visual Studio (or another debugger) to the process.  However, if you are already debugging, it will sail right past the `Debugger.Launch()` call.  `Break()`, on the other hand, will act as a breakpoint - breaking every time it hits that point (and invoking the debugger dialog if the process has not been attached).

Be VERY careful not to leave either statement in your code. Sending code with `Debugger` calls out to production can halt your application or create very hard to track down errors (bad experience last month).

Comment: Joe, thanks for detailing the difference between Debug.Launch() and Debug.Break()

Answer (score 6):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

//Lauches the JIT debug window
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

This is particularly useful when debugging a service as you get the Just In Time debugger window and can then select the visual studio window to debug the service in.

Comment: If you only want it to fire when a debugger is already attached, `Debugger.IsAttached` can be checked.

Comment: @Richard - for which line of code? the debugger does not need to be attached for Debugger.Launch as this then shows the window to give the opportunity to attach a debugger

Comment: the first (obviously). `if (Debugger.IsAttached) { Debugger.Break(); }` is a useful pattern to have a permanent break point (not dependent on debugger saving state), I usually include it in the last chance exception handler within `#if DEBUG`.

Comment: @Richard - thanks, to be honest i have only ever used debugger.launch so i didnt know about debugger.attached. Thanks for the info! +1

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [Debugger.Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx)

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```